# Pytube playlist doesn't download any video

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, pytube

I try to download playlist using pytube3 library with this code

```
import pytube
import os

# download playlist
playlist = pytube.Playlist(
    "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcjD5BAw2DxE6OF2tius3V3")

i = 1
print(len(playlist.video_urls))
for link in playlist:
    #if i < 51:
        # break
        #i = i + 1
    #    continue
    yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
    file = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download() #"D:\YOUTUBE\Gabrysia"
    # find last backslash, because it is followed by an relative path
    # and insert number in the beginning
    last_backslash = file.rfind("\\")
    res = list(file)
    res.insert(last_backslash + 1, str(i) + " ")
    res = ''.join(res)
    # rename file
    os.rename(file, str(res))
    i = i + 1

print('done')
```

First print statement prints 0, which means that my playlist is empty. I tried with a lot of playlists and it simply doesn't work. I remember that I downloaded a lot of playlists some time ago but now it's not working. Maybe there was some change in YouTube backend? But as I know there is new version of the pytube library (pytube4, pytubeX) and I installed this version and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. So adding as an answer instead.
This error has been fixed in the [original](https://github.com/nficano/pytube) pytube repository. Do a pip install directly from the repo and it should work.

Comment: I installed using pip and using conda and i get this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat'

Comment: I think this happens if you are not using python3. Also, even if you have python3 installed, conda might be running your scripts in a python2 environment. So install python3 and run your scripts without using conda.